# chrome would be hang when some web page

Tags: google-chrome

the environment is the latest version of Chrome and ubuntu 12.04. 
When I use Chrome to open web page, it would hang, and I cannot say the exact frequent. 
after I disable the flash plugins in Chrome://plugins, chrome would also hang when I open web page.
But, when the chrome hang, I could resize the chrome windows, after this action, the chrome would be active.

please help.